# How to get coordinates of a point on a Bezier curve for a certain time in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I have a sprite moving along a Bezier curve. Full time of the movement let us say is 5 seconds. what i wanna know is how can i get position of my sprite after 1.5 or 2.347 seconds of movement. Is there any standard cocos2d function for calculating this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is specific way.. Just call a method after a specific time and calculate the position... I don't think you can disturb bezier action in between and calculate the position.. Hope this helps :)